# Obtaining exit status values from GNU parallel

Tags: perl, parallel-processing, exit-code

The Perl wrapper below executes commands in parallel, saving STDOUT 
and STDERR to /tmp files:

```
open(A,"|parallel"); 
for $i ("date", "ls", "pwd", "factor 17") { 
  print A "$i 1> '/tmp/$i.out' 2> '/tmp/$i.err'\n"; 
} 
close(A);
```

How do I obtain the exit status values from the individual commands?

Comment: Retagged with Perl and exit-code

Comment: @pavel, GNU parallel, as per the subject

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get the exist status of the individual jobs, `parallel` would need to write the info somewhere. I don't know if it does or not. If it doesn't, you can do that yourself.

```
my %jobs = (
   "date"   => "date",
   "ls"     => "ls",
   "pwd"    => "pwd",
   "factor" => "factor 17",
);

open(my $parallel, "|parallel"); 
for my $id (keys(%jobs)) {
   print $parallel
      $jobs{$id}
      ." 1> '/tmp/$id.out'"
      ." 2> '/tmp/$id.err' ; "
      ."echo \$?"
      ." > '/tmp/$id.exit'\n"; 
} 

close($parallel); 

my $exit_status = $? >> 8;
if ($exit_status >= 255) {
    print("Failed\n");
} else {
    printf("%d failed jobs\n", $exit_status);
}

for my $id (keys(%jobs)) {
    ...grab output and exit code from files...
}
```

---

**Update**:

I went and installed `parallel`.

It has an option called `--joblog {file}` which produces a report with exit codes. It accepts `-` for file name if you want it to output to STDOUT.

Note that `parallel` doesn't recognise abnormal death by signal, so this is not included in the `--joblog` report. Using the solution I posted above, a missing .exit file would indicate an abnormal death. (You must make sure it doesn't exist in the first place, though.)

---

**Update**:

@Ole Tange mentions that the limitation of `--joblog {file}` I mentioned above, the lack of logging of death by signal, has been addressed in version 20110722.

Comment: Thanks. I actually tried "echo $status" after the command, but didn't realize it was "echo $?". It turns out my version of parallel doesn't have --joblog, but "echo \$? > $i.res" (escaping to avoid Perl interpretation of $?) works like a charm!

Answer (score 6):

GNU Parallel 20110722 has exit val and signal in `--joblog`:

```
parallel --joblog /tmp/log false ::: a
cat /tmp/log
Seq     Host    Starttime       Runtime Send    Receive Exitval Signal  Command
1       :       1311332758      0       0       0       1       0       false a
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid the wrapper you could consider:

```
cat foo | parallel "{} >\$PARALLEL_SEQ.out 2>\$PARALLEL_SEQ.err; echo \$? >\$PARALLEL_SEQ.status"
```

Version 20110422 or later makes it even shorter:

```
cat foo | parallel "{} >{#}.out 2>{#}.err; echo \$? >{#}.status"
```

If your lines do no contain ' then this should work too:

```
cat foo | parallel "{} >'{}'.out 2>'{}'.err; echo \$? >'{}'.status"
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of wrapping `parallel`, you can use any of the tons of modules available from CPAN providing similar functionality.

For instance:

```
use Proc::Queue size => 10, qw(run_back);

my @pids;

for $i ("date", "ls", "pwd", "factor 17") {
  push @pids, run_back {
    open STDOUT, '>', '/tmp/$i.out';
    open STDERR, '>', '/tmp/$i.err';
    exec $i;
  }
}

for (@pids) {
  1 while waitfor($_, 0) <= 0;
  say "process $_ exit code: ", ($? >> 8);
}
```