# Parallel Processing from Shell Script

Tags: shell, unix, parallel-processing

I need to call a Java program in parallel threads from a unix shell script and wait for all the threads to complete. Then the return status (either 1 or 0) of each thread should be captured. if all the parallel threads are sucecssful, unix script will return SUCCESS else if 
at least one of the threads has errroed, then return FAIL.
I found this code snippet on google which is very relevant to what I was looking for.

```
    for count in {1..10}
    do
        call_process $count $runid &
        JPID="$JPID $!"
    done
    for pid in $JPID; do
        wait $pid || let 'RESULT+=1'
        echo "RESULT - $RESULT"
    done

function call_process {
    java -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/urandom -Xmx8192M -Dfile.encoding=ISO-8859-1 com.load.MainProg $1 $2
}
```

But here the result of the Java process is not captured. Is it possible to capture the java return status as well for each process id?

Answer (score 1):

For parallel processing from shell use GNU Parallel available in all major distros. Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/6789085/2235381 and https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/